# adverb vs. adverb + enough

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> 1. Interestingly, only 38% of couples bother to get married these days.
> 2. Interestingly **enough**, only 38% of couples bother to get married these days.

What is the difference between the meanings of 1 and 2? Does "enough" add more emphasis to the sentence? We can mention other examples: ironically vs. ironically enough; etc.

Comment: Note that the adverbs do not comment on the manner, time, place, means, or any other normal feature of the following clause -- all of them comment on the fact that the truth of the proposition expressed in such a clause is interesting, ironic, surprising, etc. -- i.e, they're always meta-comment. In such a situation, _enough_ following the adverb simply means _enough to comment on_ -- it's an excuse for emphasizing the following clause with the adverbial remark.